# Problem with Syntax in Solidity with sale contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-deployment, web3-providers

Good evening. Well, I have really been battling with this and have followed instructions to the "T" but somehow i'm not getting the Syntax right on Solidity. I'm using Remix in my Web.3 Browser. I need a little help please if possible as to where I need to insert my wallet address, token info, value and so on for my tokens?

Here's the code I have been using...

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract TokenERC20 {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    // This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    // This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    function TokenERC20(uint256 initialSupply , string tokenName , string tokenSymbol) public {

        totalSupply assign = 250000000  ** uint256(18); // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        balanceOf[msg.sender] assign = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
        name assign = "PONTEM";                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol assign = "PXM";                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
        /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        require(!frozenAccount[_from]);                     // Check if sender is frozen
        require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                       // Check if recipient is frozen
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
       emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        require(!frozenAccount[msg.sender]);

    }    

    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hello. Your question is unclear. What is the exact problem ? What do you mean by `where I need to insert my wallet address, token info, value and so on for my tokens?` ?

Comment: Im not a programmer, Im very much a green horn in this field so I am not sure where to input my informations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to upgrade to solidity 0.5.

The constructor have an invalid syntax error. It should be something like this

```
function TokenERC20(uint256 initialSupply, string tokenName, string tokenSymbol) public {
    totalSupply = 250000000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals); // Update total supply with the decimal amount
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;     // Give the creator all initial tokens
    name = "PONTEM";                         // Set the name for display purposes
    symbol = "PXM";                          // Set the symbol for display purposes
}
```

Comment: And using the upgrade will remove the errors?

Comment: @Ascii124 Upgrading to solc 0.5 will not fix the errors. It is just that 0.4.18 was release more than 2 years ago.

Comment: Thanks Ismael. Any chance you can guide me how to setup correctly please? Sorry to ask but Im new at this

Comment: @Ascii124 Sorry, but I'm pretty busy at the moment.